# "make" command errors out when run from shell script but executes when run directly on cmd prompt

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, makefile

Here is my script on Ubuntu -

```bash
#!/bin/bash

cd path/to/directory
/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL
/usr/bin/make
```

It errors out with -

```
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning: prerequisite B::COW 0.004 not found.
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Clone
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
make: chmod: Command not found
Makefile:397: recipe for target 'blib/lib/.exists' failed
make: *** [blib/lib/.exists] Error 127
```

The `Makefile.PL` is present in `Clone-0.45` directory after downloading the file from `https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/A/AT/ATOOMIC/Clone-0.45.tar.gz` and extracting it.

Contents of the `Makefile.PL` -

```perl
use ExtUtils::MakeMaker;

WriteMakefile(
    'NAME'          => 'Clone',
    'AUTHOR'        => 'Ray Finch <rdf@cpan.org>',
    'VERSION_FROM'  => 'Clone.pm',
    'ABSTRACT_FROM' => 'Clone.pm',
    'LICENSE'       => 'perl',
    'PL_FILES'      => {},
    'TEST_REQUIRES' => {
      'Test::More' => 0,
      'B::COW'     => '0.004',
    },
    'LIBS'          => [''],     # e.g., '-lm'
    'DEFINE'        => '',       # e.g., '-DHAVE_SOMETHING'
    'INC'           => '',       # e.g., '-I/usr/include/other'
#   'OPTIMIZE'      => '-g',     # e.g., '-I/usr/include/other'
    'OPTIMIZE'      => '-O3',    # e.g., '-I/usr/include/other'
    clean           => { FILES => '_Inline' },
    META_MERGE      => {
      resources => {
        license    => 'http://dev.perl.org/licenses/',
        bugtracker => 'https://github.com/garu/Clone/issues',
        repository => 'http://github.com/garu/Clone',
      },
    },
);
```

At the top you can see how i am running the command from the script. When I run it directly from the cmd prompt, this is the output i get -

```
# perl Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning: prerequisite B::COW 0.004 not found.
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Clone
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
```

Comment: Does the Makefile change the `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: @Barmar OP added it

Comment: I mean the real Makefile that it generates.

Comment: According to the error message, the error is in `Makefile`, so it would make sense to post this file too.

Comment: _... but executes when run directly on cmd prompt_ : Show how you run it from the prompt, and how you run it from the script. A screenshot would help here.

Comment: Are you maybe running this on Windows?  A bad path is a plausible explanation for not being able to find the `chmod` command, but that arising from a flaw inherent in the build system of a CPAN module seems unlikely in the extreme.

Comment: @JohnBollinger It's tagged `ubuntu`.

Comment: So it is, @Barmar. But something very strange is going on here, and I am much inclined to think that the OP has either omitted relevant information (in addition to the generated Makefile) or presented incorrect information, or both.

Comment: @user1934428 - I have added the output when `perl Makefile.PL` is run from the command prompt directly.

Comment: But you did not add the generated `Makefile`.

Comment: @user1934428 - It's a file with 1077 lines. How to add such a file?

Comment: Well, you know the line of the error in this Makefile. You can post here only the relevant portions of it - for instance, the recipe where the error occurs, and those variable settings, which are necessary to understand this recipe.